# Problema con un Array en php

Tags: php, html

Quiero mostrar un Carrito de compras luego de verificar si el objeto no está añadido aún, cuando intenté crear un array para guardar los datos de la BD y poder mostralos, me aparece el siguiente error: Notice: Undefined index: Nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\Carrito\cart.php on line 80 

 Pero si se guarda algo en la variable $arrayCart, ya que me muestra un registro, los codigos son:

 Codigo PHP:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
      //Si Existe, buscamos si ya estaba agregado el producto
    } else {
      //Creamos la variable de session
      if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $name = "";
        $price = "";
        $image = "";
        $result_cart = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$id'");
        $fila_cart = $result_cart->fetch_assoc();
        $name = $fila_cart['product_name'];
        $price = $fila_cart['product_price'];
        $image = $fila_cart['product_imagen'];
        $array[] = array(
          'Id' => $_GET['id'],
          'Nombre' => $name,
          'Precio' => $price,
          'Imagen' => $image,
          'Cantidad' => 1
        );
        $_SESSION['cart'] = $array;
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Codigo HTML donde se muestran los registros en la tabla:

```
<?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
                      $arrayCart[] = $_SESSION['cart'];
                      for($i=0;$i<count($arrayCart);$i++){
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                      <img src="<?php echo $arrayCart[$i]['Imagen']; ?>" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                    </td>
                    <td class="product-name">
                      <h2 class="h5 text-black"> <?php echo $arrayCart[$i]['Nombre']; ?> </h2>
                    </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $arrayCart[$i]['Precio']; ?> </td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">&minus;</button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="<?php echo $arrayCart[$i]['Cantidad']; ?>" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">&plus;</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $arrayCart[$i]['Precio'] * $arrayCart[$i]['Cantidad']; ?> </td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</a></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arrayCart[] = $_SESSION['cart'];
```

este es tu problema.   Basicamenete tienes array de 3 niveles. Pero estas llamando a array de 2 niveles con

> `$arrayCart[$i]`

simplemente cambia a `$arrayCart = $_SESSION['cart']`

Comment: Mira, me aparece esto: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id] => 3 [Nombre] => Billetera de Cuero [Precio] => 215000 [Imagen] => images/hero_1.jpg [Cantidad] => 1 ) ) ) 1

Comment: ahhhh. ok... estas pasando todo tu carrito en $_SESSION?

Comment: Así es, paso todo el carrito de compras por la variable $_SESSION['cart']

Comment: ok, check my new answer again.

Comment: ¡Funcionó! Un error con el que llevo 2 horas, solucionado en 10 minutos Jajaj. Gracias - Thank you